# Increase numbers but not letters in HTML input

Tags: html, css, input, letter

I have this problem where I want to have an input that can take both numbers and letters. I want to be able to increase and decrease the numbers only but keep letters unchanged and also the user can't delete the letters. Like the following picture:

input with numbers and letters only:
[image: input with numbers and ltters only]

I had a workaround, by putting `<span>mm</span>` next to numbers using `position: absolute;`.

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: You want to increase and decrease the number only not an `mm`. But please tell how you do `position: absolute`

Comment: Answers are correct but they all are a workaround. none is an elegant/standard solution.

Comment: I think you should continue with your own approach.

Comment: I understand very well your problem ! i think that you need javascript code to detect the length of numbers !!! do you use react ?

Comment: I use JQuery but I thought there is way in CSS instead of using Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: .5em;
  transition: all .05s ease-in-out;
}

div:hover::after,
div:focus-within::after {
  right: 1.5em;
}

.ms::after {
  content: 'mm';
}
```

```html
<div class="ms">
  <input type="number" id="milliseconds" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check my solution below:

```css
.input-num {position: relative;}
.input-num span { position: absolute; left: 18px;}
```

```html
<div class="input-num">
  <input value="50" type="number" name="quantity" min="10" max="99">
  <span>mm</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by fixing the width of the container

HTML :

```
<div class="input__container">
  <input type="number" class="input" />
  <span class="input__text">mm</span>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.input__container{
  position:relative;
  width:60px;
}
.input{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
}
.input__text{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  tranform:translateY(-50%);
  right:10px;
}
```

Code pen : https://codepen.io/abdelhedi/pen/JjodrRq

Comment: this what I did already, the whole thing is about make the numbers and letters next to eachother and lock exactly the same. either writing 1 number or hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

another approach: text-align, padding and a pseudo from a generic structure reusable where unit can be updated.

possible layout :

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/* 101*/

[data-unit] {
  font-family: courier;  /* use a font to master size and letter spacing */
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

[data-unit]::after {
  content: attr(data-unit);
  margin-left: -1.5em;  /* fits to font-family:courier; */
}

[data-unit] [type="number"] {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 1.8em;  /* fits to font-family:courier; */
}


/* makup */

[data-unit] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 1em;
  border: outset;
  align-items: center;
}

[data-unit]::after {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
only style data-unit attributes boxes.
<div data-unit="mm">
  <input type="number" value="0" />
</div>

<div data-unit="km">
  <input type="number" value="0" />
</div>

<div data-unit="cm">
  <input type="number" value="0" />
</div>
regular untouched
<div>
  <input type="number" value="0" />
</div>
```